# How can I disable a checkbox after it is checked once?

Tags: javascript

I have created checkboxes which when clicked should call a javacript method.

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor-checkbox" onclick="addTotargetGroup($user);" id=$i >
```

But once the user clicks it, should be disabled and should not allow the users to click it again.

Comment: disable it in `addToTargetGroup`

Comment: In the addTotargetGroup method add this line of code: `document.getElementById("youcheckboxid").disabled = true;`.

Comment: do you want to disable it in pure javascript or with a framework like jquery ?

Comment: @ChristopheThiry: anything would do but outside of the javascript call would be better.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal: As you see in my question that the id is not fixed, it was of course not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `addTotargetGroup()` function to accept another argument `this`

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor-checkbox" onclick="addTotargetGroup($user,this);" id=$i >
```

```
function addTotargetGroup(user,node){
    node.onclick = '';
    node.disabled = true;
    //put your existing logic here
}
```

Comment: I can see in the debug console that it is being disabled <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor-checkbox" onclick="addTotargetGroup('Commuters', this);" id="0" value="Commuters" disabled="true">. But I am allowed to check it again as it is not working on the UI.

Comment: is it refreshing your page after cehckbox is clicked

Comment: Yes, I can see that the checkbox is disabled after the click but it gets enabled after the page refresh.

Comment: if You are refreshing the page the js is loaded back again. You have to track the disable variable send it to PHP when you reload a page or submit a form, next time the `<input>` will have `onclick="<?php (echo ($disabled) ? ' ' : 'addTotargetGroup('user',this);'); ?>" <?php (echo ($disabled) ? "disabled=true" : "") ?>` something like this. Else there is no way that JS will rememeber your disabling code if you refresh

Comment: Thanks joy. I should try that and the back end is in java.

Comment: So this  `onclick="<%= ((disabled) ? " ": "addTotargetGroup('user',this);") %>" <%= ((disabled) ? "disabled=true" : "") %>` ;)

Comment: Vote up and accept if you think this one is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `control` with `this` along with `user` to the javascript function as below:

```js
function addTotargetGroup(user,ctrl){
    ctrl.setAttribute('disabled',true);
}
```

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor-checkbox" onclick="addTotargetGroup('user',this);" id="$i"/ >
```

Using `jquery`

```
function addTotargetGroup(user,ctrl){
    $(ctrl).attr('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: I can see in the debug console that it is being disabled <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor-checkbox" onclick="addTotargetGroup('Commuters', this);" id="0" value="Commuters" disabled="true">. But I am allowed to check it again as it is not working on the UI.

Comment: Is that any customized `checkbox` or a simple one?

Comment: It's a simple one , but the checkbox is added to the server side java code

Comment: can you post the actual code here? what do you mean by _server side java code_